# Is there better way to define a command to produce a breaking mark and a source page number?

Tags: page-numbering, counters, marginnote, translations, setcounter

First an MWE and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{marginnote}
%count source page number
\newcounter{spnumber}
%breaking mark
\newcommand{\bmark}{$|$}
%produce a breaking mark and a source page number
\newcommand{\spnumber}{\bmark{} %print breaking mark
\refstepcounter{spnumber}%increment equation counter
\marginnote{\small\thespnumber}%print source page number in marginpar
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\renewcommand{\thespnumber}{\Roman{spnumber}}
\setcounter{spnumber}{0}
\chapter{Preface}


\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\thespnumber}{\arabic{spnumber}}
\setcounter{spnumber}{0}
\chapter{Fruit}
\section{Apple}
Some texts, \spnumber (from here a new page begins in B) some more texts.
\section{Pear}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now suppose we have book A and we want to reedit A to be a book B, then B possibly has different page numbers from A. For example, given some texts in B, we may want to mark their page number in A, and the `\spnumber` command serves this. But normally we cant't use such command before chapter titles while this is necessary since we usually begin a new page from the chapter title in A.

**So is there any better way to define such a command which could produce an output before chapter titles as follows? Or equivalently is there any way to use the command (i.e., any way to add texts) before chapter titles as follows?**

Note, if we added a `\spnumber` before `Chapter 1`, then the page number produced by `\spnumber` aligned to `some texts` would become 2 as follows.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I read the text a few times without understanding what you're about.

Comment: @egreg I updated the statements.